# Why std::forward() doesn't deduce type?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue

Here is code below. Why if I replace `typename remove_reference<S>::type&` with `S&` it won't work nicely? (I mean a type will be deduced wrong)

If I pass an rvalue (let int be int), then `S` will be deduced as `int`, `a`'s type is `int&`, `forward()` returns `int&&` (rvalue).

If I pass an lvalue (`int`) `S` will be deduced as `int&`, `a`'s type is `int& & ->int&`, `forward()` returns `int& &&->int&`. everything works well, so why do we need that `remove_reference`?

```
template<class S>
S&& forward(typename remove_reference<S>::type& a) noexcept
{
  return static_cast<S&&>(a);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the intricacies of type deduction rules, but why do you think `S` could be deduced at all in this situation? Whatever the kind of reference or non-reference type one substitutes for `S`, the reference gets stripped and an lvalue reference type (possibly `const` if `S` is so, I imagine) results. Since different `S` give the same result, I think it would be reasonable if it were simply forbidden to try this kind of type "deduction".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the original use case of `forward`:

```
template<class T>
void f(T&& t) { g(std::forward<T>(t)); }
```

`t` has a name, so it's an lvalue inside `f` even if it's bound to an rvalue. If `forward` is allowed to deduce type, then people would be tempted to write `std::forward(t)` and not actually get the perfect forwarding they expected.

---

Also, your analysis is not right. `template<class S> void f(S& t);` doesn't bind to rvalues. `std::forward` is actually a pair of overloads - the one you are referring to takes lvalues only, and

```
template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept;
```

handles rvalues.

Comment: The `&` overload of `forward` could handle `rvalues` just fine, though, no? At least when used in the canonical forwarding context - precisely because `forward` itself only ever sees an lvalue in its argument - what *really* matters here is the explicit template parameter specification that makes forwarding work by casting to the right type.